# Confused about life cycles and scheduling

Tags: android

I may be a bit confused about how scheduling works and I hope someone will correct me or otherwise tell me I'm right.

When I first launch my app, activity `Main Activity` is started as specified in the manifest.

(...)

`Main Activity` starts `Secondary Activity` and is then paused, while the latter run.

(...)

`Secondary Activity` reach the last instruction which launch an intentservice, said service starts on a different thread and runs on his own. `Secondary Activity` reached the ends and stops, `Main Activity` resume execution.

I'm NOT considering any external OS intervention.

Am I missing something?

EDIT: `Secondary Activity` code

```
public class SecondaryActivity extends Activity {

        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Intent mis = new Intent(this,MyIntentService.class);
            this.startService(mis);
            finish();
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand what part are you confused of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please a give a more detailed information about how the `SecondaryActivity` ends and stops are you calling finish() on it after its execution is done or calling the `MainActivity` explicitly? 
Activity do maintain a stack when you call an activity from an intent that activity is added to stack and unless and untill you do not finish the activity it wont get to the FirstActivity in your case `MainActivity`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I've added the code at the end of the question. As you can see I left finish() empty, is there a way to make sure that Main Activity will resume execution?

Comment: If you didn't do finish() in 'MainActivity' then MainActivity will resume by itself

Comment: Welcome :) 
Happy to help